# gps.next() hangs, NMEA data may be bad?

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, gps

I've got a few RPi's (0W's) running GPS.  All have worked with the same install steps and code except the latest I just assembled yesterday.  Now when I run my GPS code, I get the following prints and then nothing else.  It looks like it's hanging in report =  gps_sensor.next() ?

Thoughts?  Did something change in a recent Raspbian update?

I can cat the device and see the following NMEA data.   Should I be worried about those weird symbols?  Is that expected?  Maybe that's the issue?:

pi@raspberrypi:~/data-logger/src $ cat /dev/ttyS0
        $GPGGA,184909.085,,,,,0,00,,,M,,M,,*78

```
    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

    $GPRMC,184909.085,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,220718,,,N*43

    $GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32

    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    ,,,M,,M,,*78
        
    
    
        ����$GPRMC,184909.085,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,220718,,,N*43
    
        ����$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
    0718,,,N*43
    
        ����$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    K,N*32
    0718,,,N*43
    
        ����$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    0.00,220718,,,^C^Z^A^X^O^_^L ����$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    0.00,220718,,,^C^Z^A^X^O^_^L ����$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
    $GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
    0718,,,^C^Z^A^X^O^_^L ����$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    K,N*32
    0718,,,^C^Z^A^X^O^_^L ����$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
```

Prints from Python script:

```
    wow
    wowwwww
    wwwwwow
    <dictwrapper: {u'release': u'3.16', u'proto_major': 3, u'rev': u'3.16-4', u'class': u'VERSION', u'proto_minor': 11}>
    wow
    wowwwww
    wwwwwow
    <dictwrapper: {u'class': u'DEVICES', u'devices': []}>
    wow
    wowwwww
    wwwwwow
    <dictwrapper: {u'pps': False, u'enable': True, u'scaled': False, u'raw': 0, u'json': True, u'nmea': False, u'timing': False, u'class': u'WATCH', u'split24': False}>
    wow
    wowwwww
```

Python script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    '''
    data_logger.py

    This program is intended to record data from
    GPS         
    '''

    #import modules
    import gps
    from datetime import datetime
    import os
    import csv
    import time
    import sys



    def log_gps_data(init_time):
        #init vars
        VERBOSE = True
        TIME_STATS = False
        time_interval =   10 #sec

        glat   =[]
        glon   =[]
        galt   =[]
        gspeed =[]
        gtime  =[]
        gmode  =[]

        start=  time.time()


        #create sensor objects

        os.system('sudo killall gpsd')
        os.system('sudo gpsd  /dev/ttyS0 -F  /var/run/gpsd.sock')
        gps_sensor =gps.gps("localhost","2947")

        gps_sensor.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)


        data_dir =   os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) +  '/data'



        #do stuff 4ever
        while True:              

            end    =   time.time()

        #read data

            time1 = time.time()
            try:
                report =  gps_sensor.next()
                if   VERBOSE==  True:
                    print(report)

                if report['class'] == 'TPV':
                    if hasattr(report,'time'):
                        gtime+=[report.time]
                    else:
                        now =    str(datetime.now())
                        now =   now.split('.')
                        now   = now[0]
                        gtime+=[now]

                    gmode+=[report.mode]
        #protect for slow acquisition
                    if report.mode <  2:
                        if   VERBOSE==  True:
                            print('still  acquiring...')
                        glat+=[-99999999]
                        glon+=[-99999999]
                        galt+=[-99999999]
                        gspeed+=[-99999999]
                    else:
                        if hasattr(report,'lat'):
                            glat+=[report.lat]
                        else:
                            glat+=[-99999999]
                        if hasattr(report,'lon'):
                            glon+=[report.lon]
                        else:
                            glon+=[-99999999]
                        if hasattr(report,'alt'):
                            galt+=[report.alt]
                        else:
                            galt+=[-99999999]
                        if hasattr(report,'speed'):
                            gspeed+=[report.speed]
                        else:
                            gspeed+=[-99999999]

                    if   VERBOSE==  True:
                        print(gtime[-1])
                        print(gmode[-1])
                        print(glat[-1])
                        print(glon[-1])
                        print(galt[-1])
                        print(gspeed[-1])

            except    KeyError:
                print('GPS Key Error')
                pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print('GPS Keyboard Interrupt')
                quit()
            except StopIteration:                
                gps_sensor          =           None
                print("GPSD has terminated")
```

Comment: CLARIFICATION:

I took another pi0W that was already running the GPS logging script without an issue and updated Stretch.  It continued to work after that.  I then (foolishly) updated all other software packages and now it's no longer working.  So, it's not Stretch, but maybe gpsd or python-gps

Comment: CLARIFICATION: NMEA data has those bizarre characters on the working setup, so it's not that either...

Comment: If you've [read this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md), and understand the diffs between the mini and primary UARTs, the Bluetooth connections, etc. then I'd have to wonder about your GPS device. Have you tried swapping that?

Comment: @Seamus yeah, same result with both devices.  Also swapped the device to another pi and it worked there.

Comment: looking at python-gps, it seems like my working setups had ver 3.19, and then one that doesn't is 3.16.  Upgrading a previously working system to the latest still works.

For some reason pip won't upgrade python-gps 3.16, claiming it's already the latest...

Comment: It sounds like you've found a reasonable resolution vector. Can you move the SD card from a working unit to the non-working unit?

Comment: finally upgraded gps to latest (3.9) and had no effect.  I will swap SD cards.

Comment: @Seamus swapped the cards and the problem followed the card.  

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm going to reflash the card and then reinstall everything.  Maybe there was an error in there that kills stuff.

Comment: It seems clear it's a Python module "versioning issue", but how or why is unknown at this point. I'd do two things: 1) Copy an image of the "good" card to the "bad" card. 2) Build (re-build) an SD card from "scratch" as you've just commented, and carefully document all of your steps.

Comment: @Speedy You can [edit] your post to add clarification rather than adding "CLARIFICATION" in comments; that way it'll be clearer to other users finding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot, I forgot this portion of the instructions:

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
```